# Javascript: Function as Object constructor is not clear to understand

Tags: javascript, oop

I have been working JavaScript, even though, I unable to analyze what is happening here. Could you explain this bit further? Also, I am confused how to work with this. i.e., How i can access this with values? Kindly give me a sample work of this?

```
function InitializedArray(len)
{
    this.size = len;  
    for (var i = 1; i < InitializedArray.arguments.length; i++) 
        this[i] = InitializedArray.arguments[i];
}
```

Comment: `var a1 = new InitializedArray(2, "a", "b"); console.log(a1.size); console.log(a1[1]);` will log 2 then "a". Have you tried reading a tutorial or two on JS objects? [MDN's Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) article covers use of [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_a_constructor_function). _Any_ function that you write in JS can be used as an object constructor if you call the function with `new`.

Comment: @nnnnnn: thanks for this, Yes, I read already and have been working, My confusion over here is, this `InitializedArray` function has one argument that is `len`. Then, How i could pass the remaining of the arguments. Now, I am clear. Thanks

Comment: Ah. JavaScript allows you to call any function with any number of arguments regardless of how many are explicitly declared by the function. Note that it is more common to refer to the `arguments` object directly within the function without prefixing it with `FunctionName.`. So just `j = arguments.length`, etc. MDN also has [a page on the `arguments` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 0):

It is simple object witch you can read like this:

```
function InitializedArray(len) //len is a length of array
{
    this.size = len;  //bind len with object property

    for (var i = 1, j=InitializedArray.arguments.length; i < j; i++) //iterate over all arguments without first because it is len
        this[i] = InitializedArray.arguments[i]; //create new key for object and bind to it argument value
}
```

When you create object you can thing about it just like JSON object, so change `this` to `that`

```
var that = {}
   for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    that[i] = i+(i===0?0:that[i-1]);
}
```